# Not able to convert POJO to WSDL using java2wsdl.Getting noclassfound error

Tags: java, java2wsdl

I read through the articles for converting `java2wsdl` using `axis2`. I have set the classpath to the directory where the jar created by Netbeans is located.

```
C:\axis2-1.7.1\bin\java2wsdl.bat -cp "C:\Users\Mrityunjay\MediyProject\dist\MediYProjectTest.jar" -cn mediyprojecttest.BloodgrpMaster -o "C:\Users\Mrityunjay\MyProject\MediYProjectTest\WebService" -of BloodgrpMaster.wsdl
```

I will use these wsdls to create webservices to be consumed over internet.

Using same command 3 days ago have created wsdl but from last 2 day not working.

Comment: So what did you change 2 days ago?

Comment: I have changed my project folder.Changed POJO classes location and built jar again using netbeans in different folder.